# Trying to understand SRP when we seggregate responsibilities into different classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I'm trying to understand SRP principle and most of the sof threads didn't answer this particular query I'm having,

### Use-case

I'm trying to send an email to the user's email address to verify himself whenever he tries to register/create an user-account in a website.

### Without SRP

```
class UserRegistrationRequest {
    String name;
    String emailId;
}
class UserService {
    Email email;

    boolean registerUser(UserRegistrationRequest req) {
        //store req data in database
        sendVerificationEmail(req);
        return true;
    }

    //Assume UserService class also has other CRUD operation methods()    

    void sendVerificationEmail(UserRegistrationRequest req) {
        email.setToAddress(req.getEmailId());
        email.setContent("Hey User, this is your OTP + Random.newRandom(100000));
        email.send();
    }
}
```

The above class 'UserService' violates SRP rule as we are clubbing 'UserService' CRUD operations and triggering verification email code into 1 single class.

Hence I do,

### With SRP

```
class UserService {
    EmailService emailService;

    boolean registerUser(UserRegistrationRequest req) {
        //store req data in database
        sendVerificationEmail(req);
        return true;
    }

    //Assume UserService class also has other CRUD operation methods()    

    void sendVerificationEmail(UserRegistrationRequest req) {
        emailService.sendVerificationEmail(req);
    }
}

class EmailService {
    void sendVerificationEmail(UserRegistrationRequest req) {
        email.setToAddress(req.getEmailId());
        email.setContent("Hey User, this is your OTP + Random.newRandom(100000));
        email.send();
    }
```

But even 'with SRP', UserService as a class again holds a behaviour of sendVerificationEmail(), though this time it didn't hold the entire logic of sending the email.

Isn't it again we are clubbing crud operation's and sendVerificationEmail() into 1 single class even after applying SRP?

Comment: The difference is to use another class which aggregate all(some) operation for email. This is on design side and with SRP which said one class should have only one responsibility.(translate means `UserService` is using delegation to `EmailService`). Also you could add `registerUser` method in `EmailService` and use again delegation within `UserService`(it's only about the design side)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your feeling is absolutely right. I agree with you.

I think your problem starts with your naming style, since you seem to be quite aware what *SRP* means. Class names like '...Service' or '...Manager' carry a very vague meaning or semantics. They describe a more *generalized* context or concept. In other words a '...Manager' class invites you to put everything inside and it still feels right, because it's a *manager*.

When you get more concrete by trying to focus on the true concepts of your classes or their responsibilities, you will automatically find bigger names with a stronger meaning or semantics. This will really help you to split up classes and to identify responsibilities.

SRP:

> There should never be more than one reason to change a certain module.

You could start with renaming the `UserService` to `UserDatabaseContext`. Now this would automatically force you to only put database related operations into this class (e.g. CRUD operations).

You even can get more specific here. What are you doing with a database? You read from *and* write to it. Obviously two responsibilities, which means two classes: one for read operations and another responsible for write operations. This could be very general classes that can just read or write *anything*. Let's call them `DatabaseReader` and `DatabaseWriter` and since we are trying to decouple everything we are going to use interfaces everywhere. This way we get the two `IDatabaseReader` and `IDatabaseWriter` interfaces. This types are very low level since they know the database (Microsoft SQL or MySql), how to connect to it and the exact language to query it (using e.g. SQL or MySql):

```
// Knows how to connect to the database
interface IDatabaseWriter {
  void create(Query query);
  void insert(Query query);
  ...
}

// Knows how to connect to the database
interface IDatabaseReader {
  QueryResult readTable(string tableName);
  QueryResult read(Query query);
  ...
}
```

On top, you could implement a more specialized layer of read and write operations, e.g. user related data. We would introduce a `IUserDatabaseReader` and a `IUserDatabaseWriter` interface. This interfaces don't know how to connect to the database or what type of database is used. This interfaces only know what information is required to read or write user details (e.g. using a `Query` object that is transformed into a real query by the low level `IDatabaseReader` or `IDatabaseWriter`):

```
// Knows only about structure of the database (e.g. there is a table called 'user') 
// Implementation will internally use IDatabaseWriter to access the database
interface IUserDatabaseWriter {
  void createUser(User newUser);
  void updateUser(User user);
  void updateUserEmail(long userKey, Email emailInfo); 
  void updateUserCredentials(long userKey, Credential userCredentials); 
  ...
}

// Knows only about structure of the database (e.g. there is a table called 'user') 
// Implementation will internally use IDatabaseReader to access the database
interface IUserDatabaseReader {
  User readUser(long userKey);
  User readUser(string userName);
  Email readUserEmail(string userName);
  Credential readUserCredentials(long userKey);
  ...
}
```

We are still not done with the persistence layer. We can introduce another interface `IUserProvider`. The idea is to decouple the database access from the rest of our application. In other words we consolidate the user related data query operations into this class. So, `IUserProvider` will be the only type that has direct access to the data layer. It forms the interface to the application's persistence layer:

```
interface IUserProvider {
  User getUser(string userName);
  void saveUser(User user);
  User createUser(string userName, Email email);
  Email getUserEmail(string userName);
}
```

The implementation of `IUserProvider`. The only class in the whole application that has direct access to the data layer by referencing `IUserDatabaseReader` and `IUserDatabaseWriter`. It wraps reading and writing of data to make data handling more convenient. The responsibility of this type is to provide user data to the application:

```
class UserProvider {
  IUserDatabaseReader userReader;
  IUserDatabaseWriter userWriter;
    
    // Constructor
    public UserProvider (IUserDatabaseReader userReader, 
          IUserDatabaseWriter userWriter) {
      this.userReader = userReader;
      this.userWriter = userWriter;
    }

  public User getUser(string userName) {
    return this.userReader.readUser(username);
  }

  public void saveUser(User user) {
    return this.userWriter.updateUser(user);
  }

  public User createUser(string userName, Email email) {
    User newUser = new User(userName, email);
    this.userWriter.createUser(newUser);
    return newUser;
  }

  public Email getUserEmail(string userName) {
    return this.userReader.readUserEmail(userName);
  }
}
```

Now that we tackled the database operations we can focus on the authentication process and continue to extract the authentication logic from the `UserService` by adding a new interface `IAuthentication`:

```
interface IAuthentication {
  void logIn(User user)
  void logOut(User);
  void registerUser(UserRegistrationRequest registrationData);
}
```

The implementation of `IAuthentication` implements the special authentication procedure:

```
class EmailAuthentication implements IAuthentication {
  EmailService emailService;
  IUserProvider userProvider;

// Constructor
  public EmailAuthentication (IUserProvider userProvider, 
      EmailService emailService) {
    this.userProvider = userProvider;
    this.emailService = emailService;
  }

  public void logIn(string userName) {
    Email userEmail = this.userProvider.getUserEmail(userName);
    this.emailService.sendVerificationEmail(userEmail);
  }

  public void logOut(User user) {
    // logout
  }

  public void registerUser(UserRegistrationRequest registrationData) {
    this.userProvider.createNewUser(registrationData.getUserName, registrationData.getEmail());

    this.emailService.sendVerificationEmail(registrationData.getEmail());    
  }
}
```

To decouple the `EmailService` from the `EmailAuthentication` class, we can remove the dependency on `UserRegistrationRequest` by letting `sendVerificationEmail()` take an Email` parameter object instead:

```
class EmailService {
  void sendVerificationEmail(Email userEmail) {
    email.setToAddress(userEmail.getEmailId());
    email.setContent("Hey User, this is your OTP + Random.newRandom(100000));
    email.send();
}
```

Since the authentication is defined by an interface `IAuthentication`, you can create a new implementation at any time when you decide to use a different procedure (e.g. `WindowsAuthentication`), but without modifying existing code. This will also work with the `IDatabaseReader` and `IDatabaseWriter` once you decide to switch to a different database (e.g. Sqlite). The `IUserDatabaseReader` and `IUserDatabaseWriter` implementations will still work without any modification.

With this class design, you now have exactly one reason to modify each existing type:

- `EmailService` when you need to change the implementation (e.g. use
  different email API)
- `IUserDatabaseReader` or `IUserDatabaseWriter` when you want to add additional user related read or write operations (e.g. to handle user role)
- provide new implementations of `IDatabaseReader` or `IDatabaseWriter` when you want to switch underlying database or you need to modify database access
- implementations of `IAuthentication` when the procedure changes (e.g. using build in OS authentication)

Now everything is cleanly separated. Authentication doesn't mix with CRUD operations. We have an additional layer between application and persistence layer to add flexibility regarding the underlying persistence system. So CRUD operations don't mix with the actual persistence operations.

As a tip: in future you better start with the thinking (design) part first: what must my application do?

- handle authentication
- handle users
- handle a database
- handle email
- create user responses
- show view pages to the user
- etc.

As you can see, you can start to implement each step or requirement separately. But this doesn't mean each requirement is realized by exactly one class. As you remember, we split up database access into four responsibilities or classes: read and write to real database (low level), read and write to database abstraction layer, to reflect concrete use cases (high level). Using interfaces adds flexibility and testability to the application.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a great answer to this question by @BionicCode. I just wan't to add a short summary and some of my thoughts on the matter.

The SRP can be a tricky one.

In my experience the ***granularity of the responsibilities*** and the ***number of abstactions*** that you place in your system will affect it's ease of use and it's size.

You can add a-lot of abstractions and break everything down to very small components. This indeed is something that we should strive for.

Now the question then is: ***When to stop?***

This will depend on:

- The size of your application
- What parts of it will change more frequently than others
- Do you need to compose objects together, or most of the time your modules are independent of one another and you don't reause many objects.
- What time do you have
- What is the size of your team
- A lot of other stuff...

Let's start with how big is the team.

One reason we break our code into separate modules and classes into seprate files is so that we can work in a team and avoid too many merges in our favorite source control system. If you need to change a file that contains a component of your system and someone else needs to change it too, this may get ugly pretty fast. Now if you do separate modules using SRP you get more but smaller modules that most of the time will change independent of one another.

What if the team isn't that big and our modules are not that big too? Do you need to generate more of them?

Here's an example.

Let's say that you have a mobile application that has setings. We may say that containg these settigns in one responsibility and add it to one interface `IApplicationSettings` to hold all of them.

In the case where we have 30 settings this interface will be huge and that's bad. It also means that we are probably violating the SRP again as this interface will probably hold settings for multiple different categories.

So we decide to apply **Interface seggregation principle** and **SRP** and divide the settings to multiple interfaces `ISomeCategorySettings`, `IAnotherCategorySettings` etc.

Now let's say that our applications isn't too big (yet) and we have 5 settings. Even if they are from different categories, is it bad to keep these settings in one interface?

I would say that it's fine to have all settigns in one interface as long as it doesn't start to slow us down or start to get ugly (30 or more settigns!).

Is it that bad to construct an email and send it from your `service` object? This indeed is something that can get ugly pretty quickly, so you better move this responsibility from the `service` object to an `EmailSender` fast.

If you have a `service` object that contains 5 methods, do you realy need to break this into 5 different objects for every operation? If these methods are big, yes. If they small, keeping them in one object it's that big of a problem.

SRP is great, but take granularity into account and choose it wisely based on code size, team size etc.

Comment: Most of what you wrote is opinion. Some things are not true or mixed up. First of all I like this topic and like to discuss. Thta's why I comment on your post. I try to keep it terse. Team size is not a factor since we are using refactoring tools that extract methods into classes and interfaces from classes or classes from interfaces. SRP is no extra code. It's code that has to be written anyway just better organized. Yes, time can be the killer of clean code. But the bill will come, when we have to add features, fix bugs, change features to meet customer expectations.

Comment: I agree with the things you say. Small objects and methods are easier to use and compose. Adding more things has also a cost. People start with working for 3 months adding abstactions before they get something out the door. There is a cost for having IDatabaseReader, IUserDatabaseReader and IUserProvider instead of just one IUserRepository. I start with a good design with the right amount of granularity and then refactor as I need to. I think that SRP indeed helps with source control. More interfaces and classes with separate responsibilities -> less contention points.

Comment: Version control is not a reason for SRP, it's a consequence that it's easier to work with it you do use SRP. I used interfaces to make a point. Maybe it did get confusing and sounded like mixing things up. Implementing 5 interfaces from one class, probably will give it more responsibilities and cause a contention point. In my experience it's better to have more smaller classes and use composition. Smaller apps are easy to understand and modify. Bigger ones are harder. If the app is smaller and easy to understand I see no need to break things further.

Comment: Also saving time is important. It's difficult to get good code when you have to save time, but sometimes (not always of course) it has to be done. If we don't get things out the door in time and are left without work because the company that we work for bankrupted (or even worse it can be your own company) is not cool. If you work in an ogranization that has a lot of money and time to spare, good. If you have to make something to make money it's a different story. Does getting good unittests and SRP that will bankrupt a company a good thing? Now domain like heath care is a different story.